# use this in vue functions for item self reference

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

How can I reference the element itself in functions with vue?

I mean that:

```
<div id="foo" onClick="clickFunction(this.id)"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
function clickFunction(e){
    console.log(e) // foo
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't, you normally don't deal with DOM directly. If you need to pass foo to clickFunction then just do it

Comment: In what way do you want/need to reference the element in your function?  Knowing what you want to do with the element will help inform others how to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `event.target.id`

```
<div id="foo" @click="clickFunction($event)"></div>
```

and

```
clickFunction(event){
    alert(event.target.id)
}
```

```js
const App = {
 methods: {
    clickFunction(event){
        alert(event.target.id)
    }
  }
}

Vue.createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 1.75; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="app" v-cloak>
  <button id="foo" @click="clickFunction($event)">Click Me!</button>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```